# How to create a Model with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm learning how to use Mongodb and I was wondering if there's a comparable way to create a schema with Mongodb not using Mongoose. I want to make sure I have a good understanding of Mongodb. Currently, my app works but my requests are all in the server.js file so I'm trying to break up the file.

For example, here's code to identify a user schema with Mongoose. Is there a way this can be done with Mongodb?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is schema-less by default , which mean you can insert documents without pre-defined schema , but if you need to apply specific rules and constrains to the collection you may add schema validator as follow:

```
db.createCollection("users", {
 validator: {
  $jsonSchema: {
     bsonType: "object",
     required: [ "name", "email", "password" ],
     properties: {
        name: {
           bsonType: "string",
           description: "must be a string and is required"
        },
        email: {
                 bsonType: "string",
                 description: "must be a string and is required"
              },
        password: {
                 bsonType: "string",
                 description: "must be a string and is required"
              },
          date:   {
                 bsonType: "Date",
                 description: "must be a Date but is not required"
              } 
              
           }
        }
     }
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: How do you connect to the db? I'm assuming you don't need to have another MongoClient connection string on the top like in my server.js file.

Comment: You can use the native mongo client to connect to the database as follow: mongo --port XXXX --host YYYYY -u ZZZZ -p